# What is the reasoning behind the following Redux paradigm?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have been seeing the following snippet in a couple of React/Redux tutorials:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe();
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribe = this.context.store.subscribe(() => {
        this.forceUpdate();
    });
}
```

What is the purpose of this code?  When the component is unmounted, doesn't this code call `forceUpdate` whenever the store changes?  Why would we want that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're misreading the snippet a bit.

`store.subscribe()` takes a callback that will be run every time an action is dispatched to the store.  It also returns a function that will remove that specific callback from the store's list of listeners.

In that example, the component will have `this.forceUpdate()` called each time an action is dispatched.  When the component is unmounted, it calls `this.unsubscribe()`, which will remove that listener from the store.

However, this "raw" use of the store API in a React component is an anti-pattern.  The React-Redux library already abstracts out the process of interacting with the store, and you should use it to connect your React components to Redux.  Similar abstractions exist for Angular, Ember, Vue, and more.  There's really no good reason to write your own store subscription code.

As a side note, I'd appreciate it if you could leave a comment showing where you saw that snippet, because I'd like to go encourage them to not do that.

Answer (score 1):

Calling the `this.unsubscribe()` method will remove the previous eventhandler that is connected to the stores update event.

As it is for many tutorials, this won't be anything you will use in more complex products.

If you check, the [`this.subscribe`](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#subscribe) method returns a method you can call, when you no longer which to be subscribed to the store changes